# What should i do for logout in jsp/servlet because session.invalidate() after back button click shows previouse page

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

i just want help i have developed an jsp/servlet project on which i have created logout controller named LogOut.java @/servlet/Account/LogOut
code is here

```
public static boolean doLogOut(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    boolean Result = false;

    if(request.getSession(false) != null)
    {    
        request.getSession().invalidate();
        Result = true;
    }

    return Result;
}
```

and in servlet i'm forwarding to "/" url so the most common problem is on after logout if i press Back button in browser it shows previous page and i don't want to show it so what should i do before or after logout in servlet

i have got some thing like

```
add the following code to all ur .jsp pages :-
<%
response.setHeader("cache-control","no-cache");
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires",0);
%>
This thing is working for me even with the Back Button
```

is this ok i means i have to do it in all pages if i don't use the listener or some thing can be do...????????????

Comment: Yes, add header "Cache-control" with value "no-cache" to all pages that should not be cached by browser

Answer (score 1):

To disable browser cache JSP pages, create a Filter which is mapped on an url-pattern of *.jsp

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```